# Ffmpeg, pad Dynamic coloring of black stripes

Tags: ffmpeg

```
,scale=-2:198,pad=352:ih:(ow-iw)/2
```

I add stripes on the sides, I know that it is possible to specify their color. But is it possible not to specify the color, but to set it to the one that prevails on the frame?

Comment: See fillborders filter - https://video.stackexchange.com/q/32648/

Comment: Perhaps for the place of stripes, color and dt. Set the same image to scale or otherwise, but only darkened, in order to mark the borders as if there were black bars?

Comment: Tormented, in general it is clear how it works but too difficult `scale=-2:594, pad=1056:ih:(ow-iw)/2, fill borders=left=500:height=500:mode=smear `. in my case, you need to add black bars if the width of the image is less than the specified one and at the same time calculate what the width of one of the black bars is. actually how to find this width?

Comment: There is no solution on the fly. So that if there are black stripes on the edges. Then in these cases, first scale the (blurred) frame and apply the original one on it. on the internet, i saw similar images where the original frame is centered, and the same frame is only blurred at the edges.